# Sql command for finding IDENT_CURRENT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have got to find the last number inserted into as identity into column "ID_K" table KLIENT. How should I improve my code?

Thanks so much in advance.

```
  SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("IDENT_CURRENT klient", spojeni);
          //  SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select MAX (ID_K) FROM klient", spojeni);
            spojeni.Open();
            int max = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
            spojeni.Close();


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg_ksluzby.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value) == true) 
                {
                    SqlCommand prikaz2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klisluz(text,pocet,akce,subkey) values(@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4) ", spojeni);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", row.Cells["text"].Value);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", row.Cells["pocet"].Value);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", row.Cells["akce"].Value);
                    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", max + 1);
                    spojeni.Open();
                    prikaz2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    spojeni.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')` is correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) is

```
 SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('klient')", spojeni);
```

Keep in mind that IDENT_CURRENT is defined as NUMERIC(38,0), so I think that the best datatype to use to get the return value from ExecuteScalar is a Decimal

```
 decimal lastValue = (decimal)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

or, if your values are not too big you could use

```
 int lastValue = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
```

However this command, like the MAX(K_ID) suffers from the same problem. If someone from a different connection inserts a new record in the table 'klient' between this call and the call to the insert into the table 'klisluz' you could get a wrong number for the last identity value inserted. If there is any kind of relationship between 'klient' and 'klisluz' you should explain this because from the table name and column names is not clear.

Comment: Thanks so much, how is possible that my code with your SqlCommand is giving me this error : Specified cast is not valid. ?

Comment: Yes, IDENT_CURRENT doesn't return an integer but a NUMERIC(38,0). I think that the best datatype to use is a decimal or, if your values are not too big you could use `int max = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());